# Is iostream.h necessary for executing a C++ program using Dev C++?

Tags: c++, compilation

I tried compiling the following code using `Dev c++`. It gives my crazy errors which open up header files like `stddef.h`. I earlier had a problem when i tried including `iostream.h` but that was solved after I changed it to `iostream`.

```
#include<iostream> //header files
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
struct flight //structures
{
    int flino;
    char source[20];
    char destination[20];
    float price;
};
void input(flight flight1[],int num) //inputing details
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the flight number: ";
        cin>>flight1[i].flino;
        cout<<"Enter the source: ";
        cin >> flight1[i].source;
        cout<<"Enter the destination: ";
        cin >> flight1[i].destination;
        cout<<"Enter the price: ";
        cin>>flight1[i].price;
    } 
}

void deletion(flight flight1[],int num) //deletion
{
    int pos=0,search,flag=0;
    cout<<"Enter the element to be deleted: ";
    cin>>search;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(search==flight1[i].flino)
        {
            flag =1;
            cout<<"Element found at "<<i+1;
            pos++;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if(flag==0)
    {
        cout<<"Element not found, no deletion!!  ";
        exit(0);
    }
    for(int i=pos;i<num;i++)
    {
        flight1[i-1]=flight1[i];
    }
    num=num-1;
}
void sort(flight flight1[],int num) //sorting
{
    flight min,temp;
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=(num-1);i++)
    {
        min=flight1[i];
        pos=i;
        for(int j=(i+1);j<=num;j++)
        {
            if(flight1[j].flino<min.flino)
            {
                min=flight1[j];
                pos=j;
            }
        }
        temp=min;
        min=flight1[i];
        flight1[pos]=temp;
    }
}

void display(flight flight1[],int num) //displaying
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"The flight number is: ";
        cout<<flight1[i].flino;
        cout<<"The source: ";
        puts(flight1[i].source);
        cout<<"The destination: ";
        puts(flight1[i].destination);
        cout<<"The price is: ";
        cout<<flight1[i].price;
    } 
} 
int main()
{
    flight f[30];
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no. of flights: ";
    cin>>n;
    input(f,n);
    deletion(f,n);
    sort(f,n);
    display(f,n);
    getch();
}
```

Whenever i try to compile this code, i get the following errors:

```
Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64-bit
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp" -o "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.exe"  -ansi -ansi  -I"E:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"  -L"E:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc
In file included from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/stddef.h:1:0,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:26,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:46,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ios:39,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ostream:40,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:40,
                from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:1:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:20:3: error: 'errno_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:21:3: error: 'errno_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:26:18: error: 'uintptr_t' does not name a type

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:218:1: error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type
In file included from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:46:0,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,

                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ios:39,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ostream:40,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:40,
                from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:1:

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:105:59: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:108:60: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:146:50: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:147:51: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:178:80: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:207:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:222:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:224:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:225:77: error: 'size_t' has not been declared

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:226:77: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:227:76: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:230:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:233:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:298:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:300:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:302:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:304:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:306:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:320:62: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:321:67: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:322:46: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:325:5: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/wchar.h:326:73: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
In file included from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42:0,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ios:39,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ostream:40,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:40,
                from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:1:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:151:11: error: '::mbrlen' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:152:11: error: '::mbrtowc' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:154:11: error: '::mbsrtowcs' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:176:11: error: '::wcrtomb' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:181:11: error: '::wcscspn' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:182:11: error: '::wcsftime' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:183:11: error: '::wcslen' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:187:11: error: '::wcsrtombs' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:188:11: error: '::wcsspn' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/cwchar:196:11: error: '::wcsxfrm' has not been declared
In file included from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ios:41:0,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ostream:40,
                from e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:40,
                from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:1:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static std::size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:332:26: error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope

In file included from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:3:0:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h: At global scope:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:191:65: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:207:54: error: 'size_t' has not been declared

e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:211:55: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:319:55: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:320:56: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:331:47: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:332:48: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:412:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/stdio.h:413:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp: In function 'void input(flight*, int)':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:16:3: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:16:3: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:62:18: note:   'std::cout'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:17:3: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:17:3: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:61:18: note:   'std::cin'

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp: In function 'void deletion(flight*, int)':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:30:2: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:30:2: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:62:18: note:   'std::cout'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:31:2: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:31:2: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:61:18: note:   'std::cin'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:45:9: error: 'exit' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp: In function 'void display(flight*, int)':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:79:3: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:79:3: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:62:18: note:   'std::cout'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:93:2: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:93:2: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:62:18: note:   'std::cout'
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:94:2: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new  2.cpp:94:2: note: suggested alternative:
e:\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/iostream:61:18: note:   'std::cin'

Execution terminated
```

Can someone please help me out and tell me what i can do to solve this? Please reply as soon as possible.

EDIT: I solved the above problem. It only gives me a few warnings now:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

In file included from E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,
                from main.cpp:1:
E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

g++.exe main.o  -o "Test.exe" -L"E:/Dev-Cpp/lib"  

Execution terminated
Compilation successful
```

Isn't that one about me using iostream.h instead of iostream?

**UPDATE:** I had learned that `using namespace std;` will solve all the issues related to this.

Comment: The errors are pretty clear, IMO: `'cin' was not declared in this scope. suggested alternative: 'std::cin'`.

Comment: What part of this were you writing when the errors appeared?

Comment: if this is a C++ program, then don't `#include <stdio.h>`. Use the C++ functionality instead (or if you're more comfortable with the C stuff, then `#include <cstdio>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had compiled the code and had seen. Its working perfect. Please compile it now and see.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct flight //structures
{
    int flino;
    char source[20];
    char destination[20];
    float price;
};
void input(flight flight1[],int num) //inputing details
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the flight number: ";
        cin>>flight1[i].flino;
        cout<<"Enter the source: ";
        cin >> flight1[i].source;
        cout<<"Enter the destination: ";
        cin >> flight1[i].destination;
        cout<<"Enter the price: ";
        cin>>flight1[i].price;
    } 
}

void deletion(flight flight1[],int num) //deletion
{
    int pos=0,search,flag=0;
    cout<<"Enter the element to be deleted: ";
    cin>>search;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(search==flight1[i].flino)
        {
            flag =1;
            cout<<"Element found at "<<i+1;
            pos++;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if(flag==0)
    {
        cout<<"Element not found, no deletion!!  ";
        exit(0);
    }
    for(int i=pos;i<num;i++)
    {
        flight1[i-1]=flight1[i];
    }
    num=num-1;
}
void sort(flight flight1[],int num) //sorting
{
    flight min,temp;
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=(num-1);i++)
    {
        min=flight1[i];
        pos=i;
        for(int j=(i+1);j<=num;j++)
        {
            if(flight1[j].flino<min.flino)
            {
                min=flight1[j];
                pos=j;
            }
        }
        temp=min;
        min=flight1[i];
        flight1[pos]=temp;
    }
}

void display(flight flight1[],int num) //displaying
{
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"The flight number is: ";
        cout<<flight1[i].flino;
        cout<<"The source: ";
        puts(flight1[i].source);
        cout<<"The destination: ";
        puts(flight1[i].destination);
        cout<<"The price is: ";
        cout<<flight1[i].price;
    } 
} 
int main()
{
    flight f[30];
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no. of flights: ";
    cin>>n;
    input(f,n);
    deletion(f,n);
    sort(f,n);
    display(f,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says that it cant find iostream.h as the only error. When i change it to "iostream", it give me the same errors. I think its a problem with the way I set up the preferences?

Comment: @Hele, what preferences are you talking about? Dev-C++ knows where iostream is, by default. Or did you install the thing manually? using namespace std is the only thing that you need to make this code work. As an aside, exit is defined in stdlib.h.

Comment: Yes, i had set it up wrong. Your code works fine now, thought it gives me a few errors. I've updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, need 15 reputation for that.I'm a newbie.

Comment: I already did it. Thanks for your help :). Can you tell me how I can flag this question as closed?

Comment: @Hele - You don't have to flag this question as closed. A question is closed when it's duplicate is available in stack overflow. Your question and answers will be helpful for others who visit the site. Closing an answer requires more reputation. When you ask a question and accept its answer, you are serving the community by adding more knowledge to the newbies having similar problems.

Comment: Your original post worked just fine. Your latest edit dosen't. Why didn't you just leave the headers included?

Comment: @Hele - You said you wanted  it for a different compiler. That's why. Now I had edited it back. If it's the turbo compiler, you don't need even the `using namespace std;` in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the error?  `cout` and `cin` reside in a namespace, specifically, the namespace `std`, so...

```
cin >> whatever; // incorrect

std::cin >> whatever; // correct
```

Alternatively, you *can* bring the entire `std` namespace (or any namespace for that matter) into the global namespace with a `using` statement.  However, don't ever do this in a header as it pollutes the global namespace and be wary of doing it in an implementation file for the same reason.  Use your best judgement here.

```
using namespace std;

// ...

cin >> whatever; // ok!
```

---

As an aside, if you're using a book which tells you to write `#include <iostream.h>`... throw it away and get a new one.

Comment: It still opens up stddef.h and gives the same errors.size_t not declared, etc.

Comment: @hele, size_t, too, resides in std namespace. use std::size_t

Comment: Or include <cstddef> if you don't want std::.

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming in C++, DON'T use these headers:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
```

After the header, add: `using namespace std;`
And finally, instead of `getch();` use:

```
system("pause");
return 0;
```

It works now :)